# Binding Drop Down in Bootstrap with Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem where I'm not able to view the data select from the database into my Drop Down in Bootstrap. See screenshots for detailed information about the problem I'm facing. I used to do that easily with ASP controls by I'm facing a difficulty doing that in bootstrap. Also, I would appreciate if there's a way to dynamically add elements to the drop-down list, I mean programmatic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP2G5.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2q35.jpg)[enter image description here][3]

Comment: In the future please [refrain from posting screenshots of your code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1224112). You should paste code samples in to the question. It also appears one of your screenshots is missing. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

use runat server tag and populate from datatble from codebehind like this
in aspx file

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li runat="server" id="ddl"></li>
        </ul>
```

and in codeBehind File

```
  for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        { 
            ddl.InnerHtml += "<a href=\"#\">" +dt.Rows[i]["Name"] + "</a>";
        }
```